# I don't update both sides of a JPA relationship, but it works. Ok?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entity-relationship

These are my entities

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="admins")
    private Set<Game> adminForGames = new HashSet<Game>();

@Entity
public class Game {

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name="Game_adminUsers",
            joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="Game_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="User_id")
    )
    private Set<User> adminUsers = new HashSet<User>();
```

And this is how I create a new `Game`:

```
Game game = new Game(index, name);
game.getAdminUsers().add(someUser);
em.persist(game);
```

As you can see I don't update the `someUser` to add the new game to his `adminForGames`, though according though the JPA spec this is my responsibility.

Still, it works fine, which is logical because the `User` record doesn't actually need to be written to (because the relationship uses a join table).

Does it work "by chance" (my implementation is Hibernate) or am I actually doing this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding from the JPA spec is that it is the user's responsibility to set correct relations *in memory*.

For the *database* it is sufficient to set the owning side of the relationship (and that is what you did). So (from theory) it should not work if you set the non-owning side only.

Comment: Ok, so I mustn't expect that I can get correct info from that same `User` instance's `adminForGames` field after the transaction? I don't need to do that anyway.

Comment: That's correct. Alternatively you could refresh the User from the database to get correct adminForGames informtion.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't "chance." This is how JPA is expected to work.